# CodeCollaborator for Excel?

Tags: excel, review, code-collaborator

Previously I have used CodeCollaborator for code reviews, and it was a great joy for most kind of code in text files.

However, I have a need to have multiple people review an excel file, across timezones, and for whatever amount of review functionality in Excel, it just isn't enough.

One person's feedback using comments is already busy enough. I don't want to have everyone's comments on the same screen.

While a colleague suggests that CodeCollaborator could handle excel files, after visting the site, I'm less convinced that it could handle excel.

Would anyone know if CodeCollaborator would work? If not, are there alternatives that would do what I want?

Comment: Excel is an interesting beast. What is interesting to you to review? The grid of data you see when you open the file? The formulas? The cell dependency graph? Embedded graphs?

Comment: Basically we're currently using excel to help plan for feature interaction testing. We're going through features, and i thought it would be nice to havd a collaborative review that's painful than using excel comments. We'll replace this with an web app, and I thought if we can leverage CodeCollaborator as a stop gap, it would've been nice

Comment: Well, I happen to be a dev on the CodeCollaborator team, and Excel support is definitely on our radar, especially if we're talking "here's a grid, the columns didn't change but some cells and rows did"

Comment: @wowest That would be great to have :)